# sorting data in crystal report that contains a combination of strings and numbers

Tags: crystal-reports

i have read already how to sort data in crystal report, but i have a different issue, the data that i want to sort contain description(string) and numbers, and i want the sorting according to these numbers ascending..
the data is about description of stock item plus the weight in kg, the sorting will be according to their weight..
the data is like:

- boxes / KG +300 Kg
- boxes / KG +1000 Kg
- boxes / KG +500 Kg
- boxes / KG +25 Kg

they must be :

- boxes / KG +25 Kg
- boxes / KG +300 Kg
- boxes / KG +500 Kg
- boxes / KG +1000 Kg

So how to sort them?

Comment: Split XXX kg into numeric field and then sort by that field. Else you need to split string and get number from that string and after that you sort by that "numeric" part of the string, kinda messy...

Answer (score 1):

Create a formula like below:

```
@Splitstring

stringvar s1;

stringvar s2;

numbervar n1;

s1 := {stringFormat_.StringValue}[13 to 20];

s2 := s1[1 to length(s1)-2];

n1 :=toNumber(s2);
```

Place this formula in your report apply the short on this formula.
After this you can suppress if required...